# Is it possible to undo votedown?

Tags: support, voting, undo

I accidentally voted a question down. I thought voting up once would help my accidental move look like never happened but instead it voted up the question. I, again, thought voting down would settle the things, but surprise surprise :) question was voted down. So did I miss anything or is there a way to undo a voteup or a votedown?

Comment: While the vote is not locked in, click again on what your vote was. (Hover over the arrows, the tooltip says "Click again to undo." at the end.)

Comment: Thank you, shame on me that i missed that:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are within the 5 minute grace period, just click on the votedown button again to undo.

If the grace period has passed, either wait for the question to be edited, or edit it yourself to undo the downvote.

Comment: Editing the answer/question yourself is a terrible thing to do - it bumps it to the top of the questions list for no point whatsoever.

Comment: I always thought the grace period was 5 minutes.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: And so it is. Thank you for clarifying.